# Odoo12: err on setting remote database to be at amazon RDS

Tags: database, rds, odoo

I have odoo installed on my machine. I want the database to be connected to amazon RDS. I created the postgreSQL database on RDS and edited the conf file as follows:

```
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = MYADMINPASSWD
db_host = DATABASE-NAME.cAbC7aXWw6aE.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
db_port = 5432
db_user = ODOO12
db_password = ODOO12PASSWORD
addons_path = /opt/odoo12/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo12/odoo-custom-addonsenter
```

The above does not work, and I get the following err:

> **Internal Server Error** The server encountered an internal error and was
>   unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
>   there is an error in the application.

**Edit**:
When I go to RDS AWS log err file it shows the following message at the moment odoo attempts to connect to database:

```
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist at character 28
2019-02-17 23:33:47 UTC:XXXXX.virtua.com.br(XXXX):odoo12@odoo12:[20563]:STATEMENT: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appear to be at creation of database. While I did not solve the problem I find a work around, by first creating the database locally, backing it up, use the back up to create database directly on RDS. Those are the step I've taken:

1. Set back the config file to point the database to local server
2. Start odoo and create the dabase locally
3. Backup the database generating a zip file
4. Extract and keep the 'dump.sql'
5. Execute the 'dump.sql' into RDS using the follwoing code:

`psql --host=your_database_instase.XXXXX.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=your_user_name --password -f /home/my_user/Downloads/odoobackup/dump.sql`

6. Set the config file to point the amazon RDS again.
7. Restart the server and everything should be fine!